# android fragment sqlite how to fetch all data

Tags: android, sqlite

android fragment unable to display sqlite data in listview below is my code . i dont understand what i am doing wrong.

public class WindowsFragment extends ListFragment {

```
@SuppressWarnings("null")
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /** Creating array adapter to set data in listview */

    ArrayList<ContactListItems> contactList = new ArrayList<ContactListItems>();
    contactList.clear();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM PHONE_CONTACTS ";
    Cursor c1 = SqlHandler.selectQuery(query);
    if (c1 != null && c1.getCount() != 0) {
        if (c1.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                ContactListItems contactListItems = new ContactListItems();

                contactListItems.setName(c1.getString(c1
                        .getColumnIndex("name")));

            } while (c1.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    c1.close();

    ContactListAdapter contactListAdapter = new ContactListAdapter(
            getActivity(), contactList);


    ListView simple_list_item_multiple_choice = null;
    simple_list_item_multiple_choice.setAdapter(contactListAdapter);

    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    /** Setting the multiselect choice mode for the listview */
    getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
}
```

and below is my list adapter`public class ContactListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
Context context;
ArrayList<ContactListItems> contactList;

public ContactListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ContactListItems> list) {

    this.context = context;
    contactList = list;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return contactList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return contactList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
    ContactListItems contactListItems = contactList.get(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_list_row, null);

    }

    TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
    tvName.setText(contactListItems.getName());
    TextView tvPhone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_phone);
    tvPhone.setText(contactListItems.getPhone());

    return convertView;
}
```

}

i am able to successfully run using activity but not working with fragment

Answer (score 0):

You are not inserting values into contactlist array. contactList is empty when passed to listviewadapter.

Adding the line will solve your problem, it will insert ContactListItems object into the Arraylist.

`contactList.add(contactListItems);`

Code as below:

```
if (c1 != null && c1.getCount() != 0) {
    if (c1.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            ContactListItems contactListItems = new ContactListItems();

            contactListItems.setName(c1.getString(c1
                    .getColumnIndex("name")));
              contactList.add(contactListItems);

        } while (c1.moveToNext());
    }
}
c1.close();
```

Also in your listview code, I dont see you are displaying the values.

Answer (score 0):

In here:

```
if (c1 != null && c1.getCount() != 0) {
    if (c1.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            ContactListItems contactListItems = new ContactListItems();

            contactListItems.setName(c1.getString(c1
                    .getColumnIndex("name")));

        } while (c1.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

You don't add anything to your contactList.

Also, I'd use Query method of SQLiteDatabase instead of raw String queries:

```
public Cursor query (String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy, String limit)
```

from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Just set table and columns to tablename and new String[] {"name"}, everything else to null to select every name from table.